# Send Extended Email action throws error

Tags: 2010, designer-workflow, email

I am creating a SharePoint Designer 2010 workflow. Normal email action is sending emails which means SMTP setup is fine on the server.

But when I try Extended email action, it does not work. It says error occurred in the workflow field. Below is the error it shows:

> System.FormatException: The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address. 
>      at System.Net.Mime.MailBnfHelper.ReadMailAddress(String data, Int32& offset, String& displayName) 
>      at System.Net.Mail.MailAddress.ParseValue(String addr*

Could someone please suggest what's wrong here?

Comment: your e-mail string is not in the right format. ex test@test  instead of test@test.te

Comment: I have already verified it. It is correct. The email i have put in is mohit.leekha@domain.com